# Show network-wide rep on network profile

Tags: feature-request, flair, network-profile

[image]

All that empty space would be a great place to put the network-wide rep and badges, as appears in the flair.

[image: flair]

This would fill the space, in addition to making it more in line with the regular site-specific profile.

Comment: Any special reason you chose Oded as the example? ;)

Comment: Nope, no special reason. But i didn't use myself because my flair is a lot skimpier. :P

Comment: Jon Skeet's flair is much more impressive. You should choose his flair as example!

Comment: @nicael Yeah, but Oded was more easily accessible from the page i was on. :P

Comment: Oded is more easily accessible from anywhere... :D

Comment: Oded's head is not an empty space and you should apologize for implying he is empty headed.  Shame.